# Dynamics CRM Visual Studio Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, continuous-deployment

I am currently working on a project (CI) on Jenkins. I have to integrate the automatic deployment of my Visual Studio solution which contain Crm Plugin and CrmPackage.

In order to make the deployment automatic, i have a Jenkins Jobs which execute the task :

> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
>
> Devenv CrmPackage\CrmPackage.sln /Clean
>
> Devenv CrmPackage\CrmPackage.sln /Build Release
>
> Devenv CrmPackage\CrmPackage.sln /Deploy Release

As my solution is not yet connect to CRM server, i have the error for deploy:
"The connection to the Dynamics CRM Server is unavailable.Error: The connection to the Dynamics CRM Server is unavailable."

I can connect and deploy manually with visual studio but i don't know how can i connect the server by command line with vstudio.I am a newbie in Crm deploy and my question is how to connect the Crm server by command line with vstudio.

Answer (score 2):

> how to connect the Crm server by command line with vstudio

Check out the [xrm-ci-framework](https://github.com/WaelHamze/xrm-ci-framework/wiki). Though it's targeted as being used for CI in VSTS rather than Jenkins, it contains [a PowerShell script](https://github.com/WaelHamze/xrm-ci-framework/blob/master/CRM365/Xrm.Framework.CI/Xrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.Scripts/DeployPackage.ps1) that can be used to connect to CRM via a connection string, and deploy a package.

You might also consider the [spkl](https://github.com/scottdurow/SparkleXrm/wiki/spkl) task runner for deploying your plugins separately. Spkl is a nuget package that allows you to decorate your plugins and have them automatically compiled and imported into CRM along with their plugin steps by running a `.bat` file manually, or from your CI build.